# C# select from phpmyadmin

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem that it gets on my nerves. I want to make a select from my phpmyadmin database, but it throws me an exception. I'm kind of new to C# and I really don't know what is the problem, if anyoane can help me.
I have a table named student and this is the code(I've learned it from a tutorial,but..you don't always have a good day! :D):

```
        string connString = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password= ";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand comand = conn.CreateCommand();

        comand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM student";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        MySqlDataReader reader = comand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader["text"].ToString()); 
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Ana,
refer this this might be helpful for you 
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/242253/connect-to-sql-in-phpmyadmin-via-csharp-language

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your connection string isn't correct. Change 'datasource' to 'server', 'username' to 'uid', 'password' to 'pwd'. Each of them shall be separated with ';'.
And are you sure that there is no password for you mysql user?
See this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html